# docker-compose does not create network

Tags: docker-compose

iam trying to create containers with docker-compose. My problem is, that the network is not created and the services end up in the default network. My docker-compose.yml is following:

```
version: "3"
services:
  Nebula_pgadmin:
    image: nebula
    environment:
      - SOCAT_PORT=80
      - SOCAT_SERVICE=pgadmin
    volumes:
      - ./Nebula_pgadmin.test.dev.key:/etc/nebula/host.key
      - ./Nebula_pgadmin.test.dev.crt:/etc/nebula/host.crt
      - /opt/nebula-v1.5.2-test/nebula:/opt/nebula/nebula
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    privileged: true
    restart : unless-stopped
    networks:
      - nebula

  Nebula_test:
    image: nebula
    environment:
      - SOCAT_PORT=400
      - SOCAT_SERVICE=test
    volumes:
      - ./Nebula_test.test.dev.key:/etc/nebula/host.key
      - ./Nebula_test.test.dev.crt:/etc/nebula/host.crt
      - /opt/nebula-v1.5.2-test/nebula:/opt/nebula/nebula
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    privileged: true
    restart : unless-stopped
    networks:
      - nebula
networks:
  nebula:
```

Iam just starting to use docker and can not figure out the problem.
Thx!

Comment: whats wrong with using the default network?

Comment: they need to communicate with other containers in a specific network.

Comment: how do you know the network is not created?

Comment: It does not show up under docker network ls

Comment: I think its not reproducable. This is supposed to create a network. If it doesnt, consider upgrading to the latest version and if it still doesnt work, file a bug. Although without someone being able to reproduce it, I am not sure how far a bug report would take you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, added the networks to the file, docker compose build and nothing has been created. I used VSCode for editing Dockerfile / compose.yaml and I found out, VSCode does not save files immediately (even if I close the whole VSCode). I needed to save the compose-file manually...